# dnf not working after mistakenly deleting var/cache

Tags: cache, dnf

I recently ran out of memory on my Fedora23 although it didn't seem like I had a lot of files stored there. I found somewhere that deleting the `log` files in `var` would free some space and in a very careless moment I also decided to delete `var/cache` :/
Ever since, my `dnf update` fails saying `Error: failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'`.
I know this was stupid! Is there a way to fix it or do I need to do a fresh install?
Thanks!!

PS: `dnf clean all` says it deleted files, but does not solve the problem

---

If I run in verbose mode `dnf -v update` the output says
`Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: file repomd.xml was not found in metalink`

---

Ok, I fixed it but still have no idea how. Still, maybe it can end up being useful for someone or help find an explanation for what was actually wrong.
 - I tried to run `yum-deprecated clean all` but did not have it installed
 - dnf was friendly enough to offer me to install `yum-deprecated` for me, so I agreed. Surprisingly, installing that package from the dialogue worked.
 - I ran `yum-deprecated clean all` once again, this fixed everything

Possibly, running `dnf makecache` as suggested in the answer below might have done the job in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting `/var/cache` should not be fatal for DNF, but it could pose other problems.

For DNF specifically, which your question is about (and I don't know what else your `/var/cache` contained), try `mkdir /var/cache/{dnf,yum,system-upgrade}` and see if DNF can rebuild the cache with `dnf makecache` then.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I created the directories as suggested, but the problem persists...

Comment: @untergam Ah, thank you. So it does require local repo cache files like `/var/cache/dnf/$REPO_NAME/repodata/repomd.xml` to exist. Could you try running `dnf makecache`, perhaps that too verbosely?

Comment: solved it now (it was a lucky punch, my approach is attached to the initial question). Sounds like `dnf makecache` might have done the job in the first place. I'll still accept this answer, thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it!